# Splatting Arguments directly (w/o saving them in a temp variable)

Tags: powershell, hashtable

I got a hashtable with connection-data for various (S)FTP-Connections. Thanks to the Module "WinSCP" I can easily create sessions for (S)FTP-Transfers

Currently I'm saving the Hastable-result in a temporary variable `$arguments` and use this variable for the splatting afterwards

Even if it's just one line of code that could be spared: is there a way to avoid the variable `$arguments`?

---

**Sample-Hashtable:**

```
$preferences = @{
    "FTPUser" = @{
        HostName   = "ftp.domain.com"
        PortNumber = 21
        Protocol   = "FTP"
    }
    "SFTPUser"       = @{
        HostName                             = "sftp.otherdomain.com"
        GiveUpSecurityAndAcceptAnySshHostKey = $true
    }
}
```

**Function `Get-FtpSession` with the current temp-variable:**

```
function Get-FtpSession ($user) {
    $arguments = $preferences["$user"]
    $session = New-WinSCPSession @arguments
    return $session
}
```

---

I thought that I can use something like this (which does not work):

```
$session = New-WinSCPSession @($preferences["$user"])
```

---

*P.S: I know that this question is kind of pointless but I was still wondering if it could be solved*

Comment: It can't, the parser won't recognize it as splatting

Comment: To save lines, you could remove `$session =` and `return $session` from your function 

Comment: Thanks to both of you - I already had that feeling :) @LotPings thats true haha :-)
As I said above - it's a pointless question anyways. Was just curious

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are willing to modify that cmdlet, you can achieve something similar by adding ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName switch to it's parameters. Thus you can feed parameters from pipe.

```
function foo { [CmdletBinding()]param(
    [parameter(ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$true)][String]$arg1,
    [parameter(ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$true)][String]$arg2
    )

    Write-Host ($arg1 + " " + $arg2 + "!")
}

[pscustomobject]@{arg1="hello"; arg2="there"} | foo
```

Comment: Wow that's interesting - thank you Mike! I'll note that down :-)